# Binary Search Tree Insert Garbage Data

Tags: c++, insert, binary-search-tree

So, I'm writing a self balancing binary search tree for a project, and I seem to be having issues with the insert function. Specifically, this block of code here:

```
if(element > n->data)
{
    n->rightChild = insert(n->rightChild, element);
}
```

For the purposes of testing, I'm just using insert(root, 10) insert(root, 20) insert(root, 30) and so on. The problem happens at insert 30 though. It comes through and tries to replace a non empty subtree (20) with another non empty subtree. I'm not sure why I seem to be having this problem, as recursion is the only way I've seen this implemented and in all of the other questions like this that I've found, the answers were coded in either a similar way to this or exactly the same as this. Could anyone help me figure out what's going on? Currently, after it tries to overwrite the 20 subtree with 30, it ends up filling the roots right child with garbage data and then, when it tries to rebalance, throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, presumably because I'm trying to access a node that doesn't exist.

### Source Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
public:
    int data, height;
    node *leftChild, *rightChild;
};
int findMin(struct node *p) // finds the smallest node in the tree
{
    while (p->leftChild != NULL)
        p = p->leftChild;
    return p->data;
}
int findMax(struct node *p) // finds the largest node in the tree
{
    while(p->rightChild != NULL)
        p = p->rightChild;
    return p->data;
}
int max(int a, int b) // gets the max of two integers
{
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
int height(struct node *p) // gets the height of the tree
{
    int lHeight, rHeight;
    if(p == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        lHeight = height(p->leftChild);
        rHeight = height(p->rightChild);

        if(lHeight > rHeight)
            return lHeight + 1;
        else
            return rHeight + 1;
    }
}
struct node* newNode(int element) // helper function to return a new node with empty subtrees
{
    node* newPtr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(newPtr));
    newPtr->data = element;
    newPtr->leftChild = NULL;
    newPtr->rightChild = NULL;
    newPtr->height = 1;
    return newPtr;
}
struct node* rightRotate(struct node* p) // function to right rotate a tree rooted at p
{
    node* child = p->leftChild;
    node* grandChild = child->rightChild;

    // perform the rotation
    child->rightChild = p;
    p->leftChild = grandChild;

    // update the height for the nodes
    p->height = max(height(p->leftChild), height(p->rightChild)) + 1;
    child->height = max(height(child->leftChild), height(child->rightChild)) + 1;

    // return new root
    return child;
}
struct node* leftRotate(struct node* p) // function to left rotate a tree rooted at p
{
    node* child = p->rightChild;
    node* grandChild = child->leftChild;

    // perform the rotation
    child->leftChild = p;
    p->rightChild = grandChild;

    // update heights
    p->height = max(height(p->leftChild), height(p->rightChild)) + 1;

    // return new root
    return child;
}

int getBalance(struct node *p)
{
    if(p == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return height(p->leftChild) - height(p->rightChild);
}
// recursive version of BST insert to insert the element in a sub tree rooted with root
// which returns new root of subtree
struct node* insert(struct node*& n, int element)
{
    // perform the normal BST insertion
    if(n == NULL) // if the tree is empty
        return(newNode(element));
    if(element< n->data)
    {
        n->leftChild = insert(n->leftChild, element);
    }
    if(element > n->data)
    {
        n->rightChild = insert(n->rightChild, element);
    }
    else // duplicate node
    {
        return n;
    }

    // update the height for this node
    n->height = 1 + max(height(n->leftChild), height(n->rightChild));

    // get the balance factor to see if the tree is unbalanced
    int balance = getBalance(n);

    // the tree is unbalanced, there are 4 different types of rotation to make
    // Single Right Rotation (Left Left Case)
    if(balance > 1 && element < n->leftChild->data)
    {
        return rightRotate(n);
    }
    // Single Left Rotation (Right Right Case)
    if(balance < -1 && element > n->rightChild->data)
    {
        return leftRotate(n);
    }
    // Left Right Rotation
    if(balance > 1 && element > n->leftChild->data)
    {
        n->leftChild = leftRotate(n->leftChild);
        return rightRotate(n);
    }
    // Right Left Rotation
    if(balance < -1 && element < n->rightChild->data)
    {
        n->rightChild = rightRotate(n->rightChild);
        return leftRotate(n);
    }
    cout << "Height: " << n->height << endl;
    // return the unmodified root pointer in the case that the tree does not become unbalanced
    return n;
}
void inorder(struct node *p)
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->leftChild);
        cout << p->data << ", ";
        inorder(p->rightChild);
    }
}
void preorder(struct node *p)
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->data << ", ";
        preorder(p->leftChild);
        preorder(p->rightChild);
    }
}
void print(struct node* root)
{
    cout << "Min Value: " << findMin(root) << endl;
    cout << "Max Value: " << findMax(root) << endl;
    cout << "Pre Order: ";
    preorder(root);
    cout << "Inorder: ";
    inorder(root);
}

int main()
{
    struct node* root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 10);
    root = insert(root, 20);
    root = insert(root, 30);
    root = insert(root, 40);
    root = insert(root, 50);
    root = insert(root, 25);

//    int array[11] = {25, 5, 6, 17, 34, 2, 57, 89, 12, 12, 73};
//    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
//    {
//        root = insert(root, array[i]);
//    }

    preorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  Use `new` to allocate the memory.   Also, why the `struct node *` everywhere?  For C++, all you need is to specify `node`.  Seems like you're reading `C` material instead of `C++`.

Comment: You were entirely correct by the way, I didn't need any of that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the only problem you got but it is a problem that can cause serious failures:

```
struct node* newNode(int element) // helper function to return a new node with empty subtrees
{
    node* newPtr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(newPtr));
```

Here you allocate memory for holding a `node*`.

What you want is memory for holding a `node`.

Try this instead:

```
struct node* newNode(int element) // helper function to return a new node with empty subtrees
{
    node* newPtr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(*newPtr));
                                                ^
                                              notice
```

**Update:**

In a comment OP asks:

> That actually did fix it, thank you! Could someone explain why though?

When you did:

```
node* newPtr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(newPtr));
```

it was the same as:

```
node* newPtr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

So you allocated memory for holding a pointer - that's probably 8 or 4 bytes.

Then you started writing to the memory area with this code:

```
newPtr->data = element;
newPtr->leftChild = NULL;
newPtr->rightChild = NULL;
newPtr->height = 1;
```

These writes take up more than the 8 (or 4) bytes allocated, so you write to memory not belonging to your program. That is undefined behavior (aka "anything can happen") and from there it makes no sense to analyze what went wrong.

However, it is likely that the memory was overwritten later on (e.g. after a second `malloc`) and thereby destroyed the values initial written. So when you read the memory again, you got something different than the values initial written and from there, it was just going all wrong.

Comment: Since this question is tagged as `C++`, the return value of `malloc` must be casted.

Comment: In C++ you should normally use new node(...) and avoid the cast.

Comment: @HansOlsson - The intend of the answer is to show "the bug in the original code" - it is not for showing a better way.

Comment: That actually did fix it, thank you! Could someone explain why though?

Comment: @4386427 One can do both: malloc can be used in C and C++ and require a cast and that the size-argument is consistent, in general there is no better alternative in C. In C++ an alternative is new Node(...) that avoids the cast and automatically ensures consistency (and must be matched with 'delete'; manually unless smart pointers are used). The test-code is clearly written in C++.  "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: @HansOlsson - Seems you missed the point. Anyway, good luck teaching. BTW: In C casting is not needed.